# Why are String.IndexOf and String.Contains disagreeing when provided with Arabic text?

Tags: .net, arabic

I want to know if I found a bug in the .NET Framework, or if I don't understand something.
After running this piece of code:

```
var text = "مباركُ وبعض أكثر من نص";
var word = "مبارك";
bool exist = text.Contains(word);
int index = text.IndexOf(word);
```

The results are the "exists = true" and "index = -1"

How can it be?

Comment: _I want to know if I found a bug.._ If you say this 100 times, probably you are wrong in 99 times :)

Comment: It seems `Contains` using `StringComparison.Ordinal` which returns true and `IndexOf` uses `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` by default. so returns `-1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) is culture-insensitive:

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

[`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) is culture-sensitive:

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture.

That's the difference. If you use

```
int index = text.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

then you'll get an index of 0 instead of -1 (so it's consistent with `Contains`).

There's no culture-sensitive overload of `Contains`; it's unclear to me whether you can use `IndexOf` reliably for this, but the [`CompareInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareinfo.aspx) class gives *some* more options. (I really don't know much about the details of cultural comparisons, particularly with RTL text. I just know it's complicated!)